# Gift list open source app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a Rails 2.x/3 application for administrating Gift Lists (weddings, birthdays, etc).

Does anybody know about any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.hulihanapplications.com/projects/diamondlist

Answer (score 0):

take look at this one ?
https://github.com/andrew/giftlist/tree/master/app/

search also in google with wishlist.
https://github.com/spree/spree_wishlist